# Second order ordinary differential equation with variable coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want a hint for the following ODE:

$$y''+\left(c_{1}- \frac{1}{x}\right)y'+c_{2} x y=0$$

where $c_{1}$and $c_{2}$ are arbitrary real constant.
It seems to be easy, but I could not solve it using different substitutions.

Comment: this is an Emden Fowler equation

Comment: What methods are you not willing to use?

Comment: You made a substantial change to the original problem (after my answer), it would have been better to ask for the case $(c_1,c_2)=(0,1)$ and for the general case in two separate questions.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** The [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) are solutions of the differential equation:
$$ f'' = x\, f \tag{1}$$
giving $f''' = x f' + f = \frac{1}{x} f'' + x f'$.

So the derivatives of the Airy functions satisfy the differential equation:
$$ g'' - \frac{1}{x}\,g' \color{red}{-} x\,g = 0 \tag{2}$$
and the solutions of our original differential equation are given by:

> $$ y(x) = k_1\cdot\text{Ai}'\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} x\right)+k_2\cdot\text{Bi}'\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} x\right).\tag{3}$$

In the same way, the solutions of:
$$ y''-\frac{1}{x}y'+kxy = 0 $$
are given by:
$$ y(x) = k_1\cdot\text{Ai}'\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} k^{1/3} x\right)+k_2\cdot\text{Bi}'\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} k^{1/3} x\right).\tag{4}$$

Comment: Where did the $e^{\pi i/3}$ come from?

Comment: @Ian: you have to replace the variable $x$ with its "rotated version" fo fix the minus sign in $(2)$ and turn it into a plus.

Comment: So you've solved the case $c_1=0,c_2=1$, and $k_1,k_2$ are determined by initial conditions?

Comment: @Ian: that was the original question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Equations with linear functions as the variable coefficients can always be solved in terms of Bessel functions.